# Complete logger function that takes in a function and a string and returns the result of calling the function on each letter in the string

Tags: javascript, string, function

```
function logger(func, str) {
 let newStr = ''
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
      newStr.push(func)
      return newStr
  }
}
```

Need help making the logger function that takes in a function and a string and returns the result of calling the function on each letter in the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `[...str].map(func).join('')`

```
function logger(func, str) {
  return [...str].map(func).join('');
}
```

#### Explanation

if `str` is `abc` then `[...str]` is `[ "a", "b", "c" ]`.

Then if you `.map` to something like `c => c.toUpperCase()` you get `[ "A", "B", "C" ]`.

Then `.join('')` produces `ABC`.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply and helpful advice @Wyck Can you explain if str is abc what is the func parameter identified as in the argument ? I'm just trying to grasp the entire problem , any more breakdown on this problem and how it was solved super helpful so I can learn how to think in regards, cheers

Comment: You are asking what `func` is?  In my example it's the arrow function `c => c.toUpperCase()`.  Example of calling it:  `logger(c => c.toUpperCase(), 'abc')`  results in `ABC`

Comment: thank you ! Wish I had you as a mentor !

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you are pushing the function itself into the newStr, which will return... interesting results. Try something like this? Also, push won't work on strings. You should also move return newStr outside of the loop.

```
function logger(func, str) {
    let newStr = ''
       for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
           newStr += (func(str[i])
       }
    return newStr
}
```